# What are the books that a must read when starting instrument rating?

Tags: instrument-rating

Also, is there a book like the visual maneuvers handbook regarding instrument procedures?

Comment: [Instrument Rating - Materials to start reading?](https://www.pilotsofamerica.com/community/threads/instrument-rating-materials-to-start-reading.96096/). Such forum is more appropriate than this Q/A site where resource recommendation is off topic.

Comment: I think it's a great question and we should be helpful. A little flexibility to help someone sincerely asking a question directly related to aviation is a good thing for this Q/A site.

Comment: Define “must read”. As far as I know, it is possible to get an instrument rating without reading any books.

Comment: @757toga: It's [not a matter of unhelpfulness or inflexibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-was-my-shopping-list-question-closed), other sites are better suited for such questions.

Comment: I'm going to challenge that @Jim. Possible, theoretically  perhaps maybe, but irl nope 

Comment: @Jpe61   Well, I can tell you that in the 80’s - early 90’s all I had to do was fly with my instructor and watch my Sporty’s Instrument Rating VHS tapes.  :-)

Comment: @Jpe61 - Actually I think it was John and Martha King’s tapes; Sporty’s was the new competition.

Comment: I bet you read some book though @Jim, not necessarily on instrument flying, but something like Huckleberry Finn, maybe 

Answer (score 7):

The FAA Instrument Flying Handbook (FAA H 8083-15) and FAA Instrument Procedures Handbook (FAA H 8083-16) are great resources for Instrument flying.

Answer (score 5):

The best book on aviation weather for the commercial/IFR/ATP pilot I've ever read is the textbook published for Royal Canadian Air Force aircrew called the [RCAF Weather Manual](https://www.avworld.ca/transport-canada-royal-canadian-air-force-rcaf-wea.html). Simple, clear, easy to understand aviation weather theory. Beautifully written. Can't recommend it enough.